# Who killed Mr. Jones?

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

To solve this puzzle you must fulfill the following data:

***Murder data***

```
Murderer name:
Murderer surname:
Murder location:
```

To obtain this information here are some clues:

**Clue N° 1:**

```
43.0662899, 0.9654453 47.5183256, 18.2235143 53.2484772, -6.5926337 41.9037241, -85.8092902
```

**Clue N° 2:**

```
8919 141135 919 141208114
```

**Clue N° 3:**

> He was killed where the ones who sing his song are from.

*Note: After solving the first clue you may miss an '-ed' somewhere.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clue 1

> leads (via geographical coordinates) to places called HIS, DAD, KILL, and JONES.

Clue 2

> is made from letter numbers run together; they say HIS NAME IS NATHAN.

Clue 3

> refers to "the ones who sing his song"; well, "Nathan Jones" is a song by The Supremes, who came from Detroit.

So I think

> the murderer is called Nathan Jones and the murder was committed in Detroit.

[EDITED to add:]

> Of course, as OP implies in comments, "he/his" in clue 3 have to refer to the victim rather than the murderer, and all we know about *him* is that he's "Mr Jones". There's a song called "Mister Jones" by a group called "Counting Crows" from Berkeley, CA., so perhaps the murder was committed in Berkeley? (But there are an awful lot of Joneses and probably an awful lot of songs about people who *could* be Mr Jones...)

Comment: You are pretty close, the only one you didn't get  is the Clue n° 3, with the rest you are on point. (*He* is NOT Nathan Jones)

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course Nathan is the dad. Hmm. if all we know about the victim is that his name is Jones then it seems like there are going to be a *lot* of candidates for "his song"...

Comment: But you are right in the edit, the song is "Mr. Jones" from Counting Crows, so the murder took place in Berkeley.